# Complex Group By Query in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the below data in a single cursor but I want to write this data into another table with a single row for each member.

Query:

```
SELECT member__c, partner_category__c ,
      COALESCE( NULLIF(to_char(activity_transaction_date__c,'Mon'),'') , 'Mon' ) as month ,to_char(activity_transaction_date__c,'YYYY') as year ,
      COALESCE( NULLIF(sum(transaction_reward__c),0) , '0' ) as prog_amt,
      exported_id__c,sfid
FROM h_activity1
GROUP BY member__c,partner_category__c,month,year,exported_id__c,sfid
ORDER BY month,member__c,partner_category__c,year,exported_id__c,sfid;
```

[image]

the total of each category should be populated in respective columns & for each member there should be 1 row only. As attached in screenshot

Comment: `insert into the_other_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) select ...` - no need for a cursor

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you wrote? Does it return the wrong data? What is the screenshot? Is that the table you're trying to insert data *into*? @a_horse_with_no_name is generally right--you probably just want to run a single query without using a cursor. Paste `create table` and `insert` statements into your question.